# Array as value in mongoose schema using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am performing CRUD operations using MEAN stack. I am using `mongoose` and I have created a schema also.

**discussions.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const discussionSchema = new Schema({
  question: String,
  date: String,
  askedby: String,
  answers: String[],
  tags: String[]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('discussion', discussionSchema, 'discussions');
```

Notice that `answers` and `tags` properties should be an array of `string` type while rest of the properties are simple `string` values. Is this the correct implementation? Please correct me.

Comment: `String` arrays in schemas can be defined as: `answers: [String]`. [Mongoose schemas types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to define is :

```
  answers :[String],
  tags:[String]
```

or

```
answers :[{ type: String }],
tags:[{ type: String }]
```

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html